# Getting 504 GATEWAY_TIMEOUT when Express server tries to connect to S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3

I am using the following functions to fetch files from my S3 bucket via Node.js Express server running in EC2.

The API works fine when the server is just started. But after several hours, it takes a very long load time and then throws `504 Gateway Time-out`.

And if I restart the server, the API works normally.

Since it only occurs after the server has been running by itself for a while, and my connection to AWS breaks due to my internet after a few hours, it seems I can't reproduce it and view the log. I can reproduce it every time I leave my server running for several hours.

Has anyone encountered something like this? What could be the potential cause of it, and what's the solution?

PS. In my previous server, this issue never happens. It was simply using `getObject`. Now I am using `headObject` to get the data I may need for streaming. I wonder if that could be the cause of this issue.

```
export const headObject = async (key) => {
    try {
        const params = {
            Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
            Key: key,
        };
        const object = await s3.headObject(params);
        // console.log('object: ', object);
        return object;
    } catch (err) {
        throw new Error(`${err}`);
    }
};

export const getObject = async (key, range) => {
    try {
        console.log('range: ', range);
        if (!range) {
            range = null;
        }
        const params = {
            Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
            Key: key,
            Range: range
        };
        const object = await s3.getObject(params);
        // console.log('object: ', object);
        return object;
    } catch (err) {
        throw new Error(`${err}`);
    }
};
```

```
router.get('/files/:key', async (request, response) => {
    console.log('api: GET /general/files/:key');
    const key = request.params.key;
    console.log('key: ', key);
    return headObject(key)
    .then(async (data) => {
        // console.log('request.headers: ', request.headers);
        var range = request.headers.range;
        const { ContentType: type, ContentLength: length} = data;
        if (data.ETag) response.setHeader("ETag", data.ETag);
        getObject(key, range)
        .then(object => {
            // console.log('object: ', object);
            if (typeof object !== 'number') {
                // response.setHeader('filename', key);
                if (range) {
                    // console.log("Serving range", range);
                    const parts = range.replace("bytes=", "").split("-");
                    const start = parseInt(parts[0], 10);
                    const end = parts[1]? parseInt(parts[1], 10): length -1;
                    let headers  = {
                        "Content-Range": `bytes ${start}-${end}/${length}`,
                        "Accept-Ranges": "bytes",
                        "Content-Type": type,
                        "Content-Length": end - start + 1,
                        "Last-Modified": data.LastModified,
                     };
        
                     if (request.headers["if-range"]) {
                         console.log("Setting if-range to", request.headers["if-range"]);
                         headers["If-Range"] = request.headers["if-range"];
                     }
        
                    response.writeHead(206, headers);
                }
                else {
                    console.log("Whole file");
                    response.setHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
                    response.setHeader("Content-Type", type);
                    response.setHeader("Content-Length", length);
                    response.setHeader("Last-Modified", data.LastModified);
                }
                object.Body.pipe(response);
            }
            else {
                response.sendStatus(object);
            }

        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error('getObject failed, error: ', err);
            console.log('key: ', key);
            response.sendStatus(404);
        });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error('listObjectsByRoute failed, error: ', err);
        console.log('key: ', key);
        generalApiResponseSender(response, 404);
    });
})
```

UPDATE: The file fetching function is now this one since we no longer need the streaming feature.

```
router.get('/files/:key', async (request, response) => {
    console.log('api: GET /general/files/:key');
    const key = request.params.key;
    console.log('key: ', key);
    const object = await getObject(key).catch((err) => {
        console.error('getObject failed, error: ', err);
        console.log('key: ', key);
        return 404;
    });
    if (typeof object !== 'number') {
        response.setHeader('filename', key);
        object.Body.pipe(response);
    }
    else {
        response.sendStatus(object);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest taking a look at the CloudWatch metrics for your instance. I suspect you have a memory leak, and the instance runs out of memory or hits the maximum amount of memory your Node app is allowed.

I would also suggest refactoring the function for your route. You have a mixture of async-await and Promise chaining, which makes it difficult to follow and can make it easier for memory leaks to be added accidentally.

Do you know if it is the Node app returning the 504 or an API Gateway, or an ALB? That may also give you some hints.

If it is the ALB or API Gateway, the request either takes too long or can't be made. Node is single-threaded, so it generally needs to be clustered (locally, on the instance) to handle higher amounts of traffic.

If the Node app is returning the 504, is that coming from the app itself, or is it being forwarded from something else? You must set up returning 504s from an Express app, so I suggest looking more at that code. If it's being forwarded, then that may also clue you into where the issue is.

Comment: I just switched back to the old function with `getObject` only. Would see if it works tomorrow. There's no 504 returning in my entire app, so it must be forwarded from somewhere else. Also, the other API works fine. Just this one fetching files from S3 stops working.

Comment: UPDATE: Looking good so far. Guess the streaming feature is causing the issue of memory leak.

Comment: The simplified function is updated to this question. It still throws 504 after about 2 day's non-stop running. Restarting fixes it as usual.